# Sharing one gRPC proto file for all solutions

Tags: c#, grpc-c#

I've recently got my hands on gRPC on .net core and so far I'm very pleased with it..

the only problem I have is the proto files, for example: If I make a change on MyProtos.proto file in my grpc server solution. i'll have to update MyProtos.proto files in all my client solutions..

so I was wondering if there are ways of sharing the proto files..

I've tried creating a separate solution and placing the proto files there then reference it to all other solutions but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can distribute proto files with nuget package. Use `.nuspec` file to pack the files. For example, if your `*.proto` files are under `proto` folder `My.Server.Proto.nuspec` can look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>My.Server.Proto</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>My Server Proto Files</description>
    <authors>My Company Ltd.</authors>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="proto/**/*.proto" />
  </files>
</package>
```

Then in the project where you want to consume the files, install grpc dependencies

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.14.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.34.0">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Install your proto package:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="My.Server.Proto" Version="1.0.0" GeneratePathProperty="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note the `GeneratePathProperty="true"`. This will allow you to refer to nuget install folder. Now add `Protobuf` items

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="$(PkgMy_Server_Proto)/proto/**/*.proto" ProtoRoot="$(PkgMy_Server_Proto)" GrpcServices="Client" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The `$(PkgMy_Server_Proto)` variable will be resolved to `My.Server.Proto` nuget folder. The variable name starts with `Pkg` and is followed by the package name when `.` is replaced by `_`.

Comment: Ty, will try this solution and let you know Arthur, Thanks!

Comment: I have been trying to do something similar but have had problems with false IntelliSense errors. This answer helped me create a solution that doesn't suffer from that problem. I have created a [self-contained demo project](https://github.com/Liversage/ProtoNuGet/tree/no-intellisense-errors) using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using Connected Services can easily configure the proto reference of other projects, and you can delete the link in the project file. However, this can only refer to the proto of the local file, not the proto of the project. Of course, there is nothing for the relative path of the same solution the difference
You can also quote directly like this, the two have the same effect

```cs
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="..\Shared\Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

The book "Beginning gRPC with ASP.NET Core 6", chapter 7, describes how to create a single source of .proto files, within a single solution. The bottom line is that in projects for using one source of .proto files, you need to add  to the .csproj file with a link to the source project of .proto files.

Below is an example of creating a microservice solution from scratch with one gRPC client and three gRPC services:

1. Let's prepare the solution:

```
md MicroservicesExample
cd MicroservicesExample
dotnet new create grpc -n GrpcClient -o GrpcClient -lang C# --no-restore
dotnet new create grpc -n GrpcService1 -o GrpcService1 -lang C# --no-restore
dotnet new create grpc -n GrpcService2 -o GrpcService2 -lang C# --no-restore
dotnet new create grpc -n GrpcService3 -o GrpcService3 -lang C# --no-restore
dotnet new sln -n MicroservicesExample -o ./
dotnet sln MicroservicesExample.sln add GrpcClient
dotnet sln MicroservicesExample.sln add GrpcService1
dotnet sln MicroservicesExample.sln add GrpcService2
dotnet sln MicroservicesExample.sln add GrpcService3
```

2. Let's delete the Protos directory from all projects except GrpcService1, because it will be our source of .protos files:

```
rmdir /s /q "./GrpcClient/Protos"
rmdir /s /q "./GrpcService2/Protos"
rmdir /s /q "./GrpcService3/Protos"
```

3. Next, manually, using the notepad editor, sequentially edit each of the project files (do not forget to save the changes Ctrl+S):

```
notepad "./GrpcClient/GrpcClient.csproj"
notepad "./GrpcService2/GrpcService2.csproj"
notepad "./GrpcService3/GrpcService3.csproj"
```

a) remove the following three lines:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
</ItemGroup>
```

b) and add the following lines instead of the deleted lines:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="..\GrpcService1\Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server">
    <Link>Protos\greet.proto</Link>
  </Protobuf>
</ItemGroup>
```

4. Then, also manually, we edit each of the services in each of the projects:

```
notepad "./GrpcClient/Services/GreeterService.cs"
notepad "./GrpcService2/Services/GreeterService.cs"
notepad "./GrpcService3/Services/GreeterService.cs"
```

at the beginning of each service we add:

```
using GrpcService1;
```

5. At the end, launch Visual Studio and open the MicroservicesExample.sln solution and run it. If everything is done correctly, the solution will successfully build and run with a single source of .protos files.

In the screenshot you can see the result, where you can see that all projects refer to the same source of .proto files:

[image]

Comment: I believe the question was about multiple solutions. As pointed out in one of the above answers NuGet might be one of the options.