# Shared gRPC protobuf files in multiple projects

Tags: c#, microservices, grpc, protobuf-net, grpc-c#

is it possible to have for example one project for storing only protobuf files and other projects which links these shared protobuf files and compiling it with protoc? I have quite big microservice architecture with multiple gRPC channels between each microservice and there are many duplicit messages. These reusable messages I would like to put in that shared project I mentioned before and only set links to these files.

I found here some answers how to do it, but only for one project which links shared protobuf files. So I have one shared protobuf files project and one project which links these files. It works, but!
When I use second project with same link technique then build fails with error:
*The type 'Message' exists in both 'ProjA' and 'ProjB'*

The problem is that both projects runs protoc compiler and generates implementation of shared protobufs in project's obj folder. Then C# compiler sees both implementations which are the same but in two separate projects. Shared protobuf files has *csharp_namespace* option set corresponding to project structure. Each project containing **Grpc.Tools** Nuget can be build, so protobuf files and csproj linking is correct.

For better understanding of project structure:

```
Proj: Contracts.Grpc
- entities.proto
- common.proto

Proj: Microservice1.Contracts.Grpc (contains protoc)
* links Contracts.Grpc
- microservice2_connection.proto

Proj: Microservice2.Contracts.Grpc (contains protoc)
* links Contracts.Grpc
- microservice1_connection.proto

Proj: Microservice1
* links Microservice1.Contracts.Grpc, Microservice2.Contracts.Grpc
- Microservice2ConnectionClient.cs (uses microservice2_connection.proto client)
- Microservice1ConnectionService.cs (uses microservice1_connection.proto service)

Proj: Microservice2
* links Microservice1.Contracts.Grpc, Microservice2.Contracts.Grpc
- Microservice1ConnectionClient.cs (uses microservice1_connection.proto client)
- Microservice2ConnectionService.cs (uses microservice2_connection.proto service)
```

So **Microservice1.Contracts.Grpc** and also **Microservice2.Contracts.Grpc** generate C# implementations of *entities.proto* and *common.proto*. **Microservice1** project and **Microservice2** project then throws exception that types exists in both projects.

I hope I discribed it properly, if no, please ask.

Comment: Couldn't you just have 1 project which compiles the protobuf files and then reference that project like you would reference any other normal C# project? I don't see a need for multiple projects to compile the same files.

Comment: You can simply create a "common" project, where all the common protobuf messages will be written, and have the other projects reference that common project, just like you would if you where manually writing the message classes in c#

Comment: I'm trying to have one shared project, where the common protobuf files will be. But in microservices architecture you want to have separate logic for each microservice with specific grpc contract. And if I compile shared protobuf files directly in their project, then I will not be able to use it in another protobuf.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sharing one gRPC proto file for all solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66844211/sharing-one-grpc-proto-file-for-all-solutions)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Code First gRPC in .net.[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/code-first?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

you can create class library to share the definition among services (contract).
in this case you have service definition like

```
namespace RPCChannelCommons.Services.BenchmarkChannelService
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IBenchmarkChannelService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Task<BenchmarkByYearResponse> GetBenchmarkByYear(BenchmarkByYearRequest benchmarkByYearRequest);

        [OperationContract]
        Task<BenchmarkByLactationResponse> GetBenchmarkByLactation(BenchmarkByLactationRequest benchmarkByLactationRequest);


    }
}
```

and this can be implemented in any project as Server.
and about request and response model, they will defined as (here is the example for BenchmarkByYear request and response)

```
namespace RPCChannelCommons.Services.BenchmarkChannelService.Models
{

    [DataContract]
    public class BenchmarkByYearRequest
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public string Index { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string Group { get; set; }


    }
}
```

```
namespace RPCChannelCommons.Services.BenchmarkChannelService.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class BenchmarkByYearResponse
    {
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public string Benchmark { get; set; }
    }
}
```

after implementing concrete for above service contract you have to add service to your server project program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddCodeFirstGrpc(cnf =>
{
    cnf.MaxSendMessageSize = 4* 1024 * 1024; //2 * 1024 * 1024 = 2MB
    cnf.MaxReceiveMessageSize = 4* 1024 * 1024;

}); 

//BenchmarkRPCService is a concrete of IBenchmarkChannelService
app.MapGrpcService<BenchmarkRPCService>();
```

and Client parties just need to call

```
_RPCClient = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:port", new GrpcChannelOptions
            {
                HttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler
                {
                    EnableMultipleHttp2Connections = true,

                },
                MaxReceiveMessageSize = 4* 1024 * 1024
            });
```

```
var GlobalBenchmarkRPCClient = _RPCClient.CreateGrpcService<IBenchmarkChannelService>();
var GlobalBenchmarkByLactationObj = await GlobalBenchmarkRPCClient.GetBenchmarkByLactation(new BenchmarkByLactationRequest { Index = Index,Group = herdInfo.Message.Group});
```

**Advantages:**

- this implementation decouples the parties (server/clients). in protobuf first the communication parties are tight coupled since they have to directly refer the protobuf from the server project and build it.

**DisAdvantage:**

- this implementation just works for .NET parties in communication.you cant use it if you have eg: python client for the same server.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. We know about code first gRPC, but unfortunately it cannot be used in our case. We have to use protobuf files and protocompiler.
However! I resolved it by putting all protobuf files into one shared project and then compile all files together. It is not as fancy as separate projects for each microservice, but it is good enough.